# Rotate a Bitmap(a clocks hand) in a corner of Surface View, like an old stop watch timer?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to make an app, in which at the bottom corner is a mock timer with the seconds-hand(needle) going round and round like an old stop watch. My dial and needle are .png files drawn out in the "onDraw(Canvas canvas)", that is repeatedly called by my GameLoopThread(no problem here). The needle is rotated by separate anchor points which I have tested, this too works fine.

PROBLEM: when the new angle of the needle is calculated and is drawn, it appears on the top/left point of the surface view, possibly (0,0). while i need it at the bottom corner where i am drawing my dial!?

Heres my code

```
private void rotateCalc() {
         matrix = new Matrix();
          newAngle++;
           matrix.postRotate(newAngle, 95, 10);//anchor points(95,10) for rotation
    }

      @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           canvas.drawBitmap(dialimg, null, dstbmp, null);
           canvas.drawBitmap(needle, null,dstneedle,null);

           rotateCalc();
           canvas.drawBitmap(needle, matrix, null);

      }
```

I guess its possibly because when using .drawBitmap method with matrix, i am not able to pass the Rect(demensions) or x,y (cordinates), that i would want the rotated Bitmap to be drawn to.

An idea how i may get around this?

Comment: matrix.postTranslate

Comment: Brilliant works like a charm, Just what i was looking for, NOW.. one thing:- This changed the size of my needle, its no longer the one i had down sized to fit my requirement!... Any idea to bring it back to its originalsize?

Comment: translate is NOT scale so it cannot change the size

Comment: Sorry, what i meant is- the .png file of the needle is much larger than the size i require, So i put it in a Rect and downsize it by 50%, so it fits my Dial on the bottom. Now when i do .postTranslate... it does what i want, but somehow with the original size of the needle(ie the large size)... so how do i resize it to fit my dial again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this way inefficient when you compare with Creating a bitmap in which you can scale it and apply the matrix in the same function?

After that its the regular onDraw method on the new bitmap we have created

Comment: Not sure but i learnt this- postScale will scale your image according to what it appears on that particular screen. ie if it appears naturally as 160 width a .5 scale = 80width. but not by what you designed it in Corel/Ai/photoshop if in that software it showed it to you originally as 100pixels!

Answer (score 1):

WOW! that works well. Heres my code, just checking if this sequence is fine? no particular logical order, right?

```
private void rotateCalc() {
         matrix = new Matrix();

           i++;
           matrix.postRotate(i, 145, 8);
           matrix.postScale(0.5f, 0.5f);
           matrix.postTranslate(149, 337);

    }
```

One last question, Im finding the Bitmaps to be a little choppy, as in.. I mean jagged, not really smooth. what can be done about that?

I've read to encorporate "Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888", is that really needed? If so, could you give me an example. Thanx a lot @pskink, you've been a great help

**EDIT**
its very important to call  matrix.postRotate(angle, x, y) ONLY after  matrix.postScale(dx, dy), Because if you rotate first you will have to calculate the Anchor Points on the basis of the original Image you have chosen as your Bitmap. I preferred Scaling it, then finding out the new Width/Height and then deciding my anchor points.